# glReadPixels returns zeroes with multi-sampling

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am writing OpenGL app for iOS, and I need to take in-app screenshot of rendered scene. All is working ok when I am not using multi-sampling. But when I turn multi-sampling on, `glReadPixels` does not return the correct data (scene is drawn correctly - graphics quality is much better with multi-sampling).

I already checked bunch of similar questions at SO, and on some other places, but none of them solve my problem, since I am already doing it on proposed ways:

1. I am taking screenshot after buffers are resolved, but before render buffer is presented.
2. `glReadPixels` does not return error.
3. I tried even to set `kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking` to `YES` and to take screenshot after buffer is presented - does not work either.
4. I support `OpenGLES 1.x` rendering API (context initialised with `kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1`)

Basically I am out of ideas what can be wrong. Posting question on SO is my last resort.

This is the relevant source code:

**Creating frame buffers**

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer
{

    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

    // Multisample support

    glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &sampleFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, sampleFramebuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &sampleColorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleColorRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_RGBA8_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleColorRenderbuffer);

    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleDepthRenderbuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, 4, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, sampleDepthRenderbuffer);

    // End of multisample support

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
        NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Resolving buffers part and taking snapshot**

```
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, viewFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, sampleFramebuffer);
    glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE();
    [self checkGlError];

    //glFinish();

    if (capture)
        captureImage = [self snapshot:self];    

    const GLenum discards[]  = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES};
    glDiscardFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE,2,discards);

    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);    

    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

**Snapshot method (basically copied from apple docs)**

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview
{

    // Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
    // If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point,
    // this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
    // Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.    
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);


    NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));

    // Read pixel data from the framebuffer
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
    [self checkGlError];
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    [self checkGlError];

    // Create a CGImage with the pixel data
    // If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
    // otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    // OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
    // Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS
    NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
        // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
        // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
        CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
        widthInPoints = width / scale;
        heightInPoints = height / scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
    }
    else {
        // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
        widthInPoints = width;
        heightInPoints = height;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
    }

    CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
    // Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
    // The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

    // Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Clean up
    free(data);
    CFRelease(ref);
    CFRelease(colorspace);
    CGImageRelease(iref);

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You resolve the multisample buffers as usual by doing a `glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE` after binding the `viewFramebuffer` as draw framebuffer and the `sampleFramebuffer` as read framebuffer. But did you also remebember to bind the `viewFramebuffer` as read framebuffer (`glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer)`) then before the `glReadPixels`? `glReadPixels` will always read from the currently bound read framebuffer and if you didn't change this binding after the multisample resolve, this will still be the multisample framebuffer and not the default one.

I also found your `glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer)`-calls quite irritating, because that doesn't really do anything meaningful, the currently bound renderbuffer is only relevant for functions working on renderbuffers (practically only `glRenderbufferStorage`) (but it may also be that ES does something meaningful with it and binding it is required for `[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES]` to work). But nevertheless maybe you thought that this binding also controls the buffer that `glReadPixels` will read from, but this is *not* the case, it will always read from the current *framebuffer* bound to `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it in around 12 hours when I get to my computer, and I will accept your answer if it solves my problem. I didn't bind framebuffer after multisample resolve, so your answer makes sense. For some reason I thought that glResolveMultisampleFramebufferAPPLE do this automatically. (I was searching for documentation of this method with no luck). Regarding glBindRenderBufferOES you could be right, but all of above code is more or less copy-paste from apple example, so I just wanted to play safe :)